# Как переопределить массив наследуемого класса?

Tags: php, laravel

в общем есть админка voyager она создала модель Page

```
<?php

namespace TCG\Voyager\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;

class Page extends Model
{
    use Translatable;

    protected $translatable = ['title', 'slug', 'body'];
}
```

мне нужно в пользователькой части этот массив $translatable дополнить чтобы было

```
protected $translatable = ['title', 'slug', 'body','excerpt', 'seo_title',  'meta_description',  'meta_keywords'];
```

вот мой класс

```
<?php

namespace App;

use TCG\Voyager\Models\Page as PageVoyager;

class Page extends PageVoyager
{

    protected $translatable = ['title', 'slug', 'body','excerpt', 'seo_title',  'meta_description',  'meta_keywords'];

}
```

но так все равно программа берет данные только из родителя

Comment: А вы поменяли Model name в редакторе BREAD?
https://i.imgur.com/DpT4aku.png

Comment: именно вы правильно сказали. спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте названием модели (Model name) в редакторе BREAD.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо а не подскажете вот все работает, но исчезла теперь на dashboard блок отображения Pages как на заставке сразу  1 User, 4 Post и 1 Pages было а стало 1 User, 4 Post